# Can [LocationManager didEnterRegion] Get a Beacon's Major & Minor?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I got a few beacons from Roximity and from what I have gathered, ALL Roximity beacons have the same UUID. I know that I can get the major and minor values using `[locationManager: didRangeBeacons: inRegion:]` but if I setup `[locationManager didEnterRegion]` to send a push notification, and my user walks by a different Roximity beacon, that is associated with someone else's app, how can I determine this in `[locationManager didEnterRegion]` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically have two choices.

1. Define the regions that you are monitoring so they include your specific major and minor numbers.  The main limitation is that iOS only lets you monitor 20 regions simultaneously, meaning you can only do this for 20 different iBeacons:

   ```
   CLBeaconRegion *region1 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281"] major:1201 minor:3211 identifier:@"beacon1"];    
   [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region1];    
   CLBeaconRegion *region1 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281"] major:1798 minor:2122 identifier:@"beacon2"];    
   [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region2];
   ...
   ```
2. Monitor a Region based only on the UUID, but also do Ranging on this same Region simultaneously.  You will get Ranging callbacks for every specific iBeacon you see.  (Even in the background you will get this for about 5 seconds after entering the Region.)  In the Ranging callback, you check the major/minor numbers of the beacons you see and compare them to a list of the ones you own.  Only if you see a match do you perform a specific action.  Keeping this list up-to-date in your app might be difficult if you keep adding beacons, so you might want to use a web service like [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.com) that lets you store your list of iBeacon identifiers in the cloud.

   ```
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
      for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        if ([self isMyBeaconWithMajor: beacon.major minor: beacon.minor]) {
           // Yes, this is my beacon!  Do something special here
        }
      }
   }

   -(BOOL)isMyBeaconWithMajor: (NSNumber *)major minor: (NSNumber *)minor {
     // TODO: write code here that returns YES if the major and minor belong to you
   }
   ```

Another final possibility (admittedly a bit outside what you are asking) is to use beacons with a custom UUID, which makes things a lot easier.  Full disclosure:  I am an employee a company that sells iBeacons with customizable identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I was trying to do option #2 yesterday but wasn't quite working. Will take another look at it.

Comment: Would using unique UUID for each beacon not limit you to only monitoring for up to 20 at a time?

Comment: True, but that isn't quite what I am proposing.  If you define your own unique ProximityUUID and use the same one for all your own iBeacons, you will be pretty certain that when you see that ProximityUUID the iBeacons belong to you.

Comment: David, if you utilize #2, is there a way to get only one callback (like didEnterRegion: and didExitRegion: are only called once on a boundary crossing)? didRangeBeacons: gets called every second. Also, is there an easy way to get 'didExit' functionality using this ranging? It seems like when you exit a beacon's area (but enter another beacon's area, so you still haven't exited the 'region'), that first beacon would just drop out of the array of ranged beacons.

Comment: Using option #2 you will get multiple calls after region entry, and you won't get any callbacks on region exit.  You have to write extra code to take care of this: you can maintain a NSMutableArray of all the unique beacons (same uuid/major/minor) seen and update it in the ranging callback.  You can then access this array in the region exit callback, so you know which beacons disappeared.  Of course, it is possible that *additional* beacons were seen after the 5 seconds of background ranging time expires, but your app will never know about them.  With option #2 you must accept this limitation.

Comment: @davidgyoung i want to know the proximity of the beacon ... is that possible using didEnterRegion ? I want to trigger something only when beacon's proximity is near or immediate... Is that possible ?

Comment: If you want to know how far you are from a beacon, you cannot use didEnterRegion.  You have to use `didRangeBeacons:InRegion:`  Be aware, though, that there is a limitation on how long you can range in the background, generally about 10 seconds before the OS puts your app to sleep.

Answer (score -1):

You can Determinate the major and minor with this code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
     CLBeaconRegion *r = (CLBeaconRegion *) region;
     NSLog(@"UUID %@, major %@, minor %@", r.proximityUUID, r.major, r.minor);
     [self myNotification:@"You are in the region"];
     [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:r];
}
```

Comment: this delegate method returns the region being monitored. Basically, it says "hey, that region you told me to monitor was just entered" it doesn't tell you anything about the beacon advertising that region.

Thus, the major and minor value returned would your own, not that of the beacon region which triggered the notification.